# Angular 2 passing parameter to component through HTML

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-components

I'm new to Angular 2 and I'm facing a difficulty in passing a parameter to  component through HTML..I made some researches and I applied them but nothing worked

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({

  //  inputs: ['value : value'], // I tried this too

    template: `<h1>{{value}}</h1>
  <br> <p>  Hello Angular2 </p>
<hr>
  `,
})

    export class AppComponent {

@Input('value') value: string;
}
```

and I called my component in index.html like this

```
<symfony-loves-angular [value]="user">Let me think...</symfony-loves-angular>
```

but it only showed Hello Angular2, and didn't show the {{value}} that I passed!

Thank you in advance :) I really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try...

```
export class AppComponent {
  ...
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , Yes I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: constructor(value:string) {
    this.value = value;
  }I just added the type in the constructor and this is what it shows in console :
core.umd.js:2843 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: Error: No provider for String! Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for String! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoProviderError {_nativeError: Error: No provider for String!
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor]